# Node JS Server run but don't work, what i can do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

I am creating a login system using React JS, Node JS(Express, Express-session, cookieParser, bodyParser, express-vaidator, pg, bcrypt and cors ) and PostgresSQL but my node js server run but don't response.No errors printed on server console!

This my Node JS code:

```js
var http = require('http') // Importa a biblioteca http
const express = require('express'); //Importa a biblioteca express
const session = require('express-session'); //Importa a biblioteca express
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'); //Importa a biblioteca express
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); //Importa a biblioteca express
const { body, validationResult } = require('express-validator')
const { Pool } = require('pg') //Importa o gerenciador de coneção ao Postgress
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const cors = require("cors")

const app = express(); //Inicializa um app express
app.use(express.json());
app.use(
    cors()
);
app.use(cookieParser)
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 

app.use(
    session({
        key: "userId",
        secret: "subscribe",
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        cookie: {
        expires: 60 * 60 * 24,
        },
    })
);

const pool = new Pool({ //Cria o gerenciador passando como parametro um objeto com as configurações necessárias
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'postgres',
    password: 'root',
    database: 'testOnfinity',
    post: 5334
})

function loginUser(email, senha, callback) { //Função responsável de verificar se o usuário pode executar o login
    console.log('Conectando...')
    pool.connect((error, client, release) => {
        if (error) { //Se houver erro na conexão retorna o erro completo
            return console.error('Erro na conexão: ', error)
        } else {
            console.log('Conectado!')
        }
        client.query(`SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = '${email}';`, (error, result) => {
            release() 
            if (error) { //Se houver erro na execução da query retorna o erro completo
                console.error('Erro na execução da query: ', error.stack)
            } else {
                console.log("Macthes: ", result.rows.length)
                if(result.rows.length > 0){
                    bcrypt.compare(senha, result.rows[0].senha, (error, responseCompare) => {
                        req.session.user = result.rows
                        console.log(req.session.user)
                        callback(responseCompare)
                    })
                }
            }
        })
    })
}

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    if(req.session.email){
        console.log('Session ON')
    } else {
        console.log('Session OFF')
        res.redirect('/login')
    }
    res.json({
        message: "teste"
    })
})
app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    console.log("GET NO LOGIN")
})
app.post('/login',[
    body("emailInput").isEmail().normalizeEmail().withMessage('Este não é um email válido'),
    body("senhaInput").isLength({min: 8, max: 16}).trim().withMessage('Sua senha precisa ter entre 8 e 16 caracteres')
], (req, res, next) => { 
    console.log('REQUISIÇÂO AO SERVIDOR CHEGOU')
    const senha = req.body.senhaInput
    const email = req.body.emailInput
   
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if(!errors.isEmpty()){
        return res.json({errors: errors.array()} )
    }
    console.log(req.body)
    loginUser(email, senha, result => {
        if(result){
            req.session.email = "teste"
        }
        res.json({
            email: email,
            isLogado: result
        });
    })
}) 

app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log("Servidor escutando na porta 8080...")
});
```

I am run using nodemon so i jus recive this out:
"[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
Servidor escutando na porta 8080..."

When i try acess "http://localhost:8080/" i recive a eternal loading!

You can help me?
Sorry, I am from Brazil and my englih not is very good!

Comment: you are redirecting "/" to "/login" but login doesn't respond with a res

Comment: Unrelated, but get rid of those comments on your imports. They are utterly useless and just adding noise (some of them are even wrong copy&paste even w/o understanding your language).

Answer (score 0):

I rebooted my computer and the error stopped.

Answer (score 0):

My be the problem was that the used port was taken by another processes, so when you rebooted the computer it worked.

Comment: Rather than an answer, this is a comment that should have been written below the main question using "add a comment"